# Suspended while debugging Android with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, classcastexception

Here is part of my Activity codes:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IParser = new ImageParser(MainActivity.this, EarthqpicUrl);
                IParser.execute();
            }
        });
```

And this is part of my AsyncTask Codes:

```
AsyncResponse lempar; *//this is An interface*
public ImageParser(Context actv, String EarthqpicUrl){
   this.actv=actv;
   this.EarthqpicUrl=EarthqpicUrl;
   this.lempar = (AsyncResponse) actv;
}
```

This is the interface code:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    public void processFinish(Bitmap output);
}
```

I use the same code for parsing a JSONData, It works. But when I use the same constructor after some modification like class name, it show an error while debugging:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (Exception ClassCastException))
ImageParser.<init>(Context, String) Line:25
MainActivity$1.onCllick(View) line: 23
```

what's wrong with this code?
Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot

These is part of codes I use in JSONParser:

```
AsyncResponse delegate;

public JSONParser(Context actv,String url){
    this.actv=actv;
    this.url = url;
    this.delegate = (AsyncResponse) actv;
}
```

same as JSONParser, I use an interface named AsyncResponse.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting an object of type `Context` to `AsyncResponse`:

```
this.lempar = (AsyncResponse) actv;
```

This is what's causing the error.

Comment: Thanx for reply, but I use this way because it works before for JSONParser instead of ImageParser. With the same code, why it can't work for ImageParser? Would you help me @vikram ?

Comment: Problem Solved. Found that it have to implements interface in MainActivity Class.

Comment: @stsho89 Sorry, I assumed from the beginning that you had already implemented the `AsyncResponse`interface in `MainActivity` because your `JSONParser` was functioning. Glad that your issue is solved.